# KeyError: 2 When using large values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

So I had to write a program to sort the SAMPLE ID NO's of plants according to their heights into a list (ascending order of heights), I made a code and it works only for small values. When I put large values, it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/plant_hieght_id.py", line 15, in <module>
  del d[int(w[0])]
KeyError: 2
```

My code can be found at: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=TXQ94tUy

Comment: You should add the code here, instead of linking it.

Comment: It's a bad assumption to think that we'll understand what you wanted to do by reading your code...

Comment: You're doing the following in a loop: `d[id]=ht` - how many different values do you think will `d` have by the time the execution exits the loop ?

Comment: @alfasin: No one asked you to "research" what my code does. If you read, i have explained what i wanted to do with it, in the question.
Also the loop will run n times. That is the range i have given. It is a for loop with range (0,n). N is an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had to write a program to sort the SAMPLE ID NO's of plants
>   according to their heights into a list (ascending order of heights)

So if `d` contains the mapping of ids to heights and you want to obtain a sequence of ids sorted by ascending order of height you want to do:

```
e = sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k], reverse=True)
```

- Iterating over a dictionary iterates over the keys so `sorted(d)` is the same as `sorted(d.keys())`.
- By specifying `key=lambda k: d[k]` you can customize how the comparisons are performed. Here the comparisons are done on the values `d[k]` instead of the keys
- Using `reverse=True` the sorting is in descending order. (In your question text you say ascending order but the code you provide doesn't do that. If it's really ascending that you want just remove the `reverse=True` parameter)

---

The problem with your original code is that:

```
w=list(d.fromkeys(str(q)))
```

The `fromkeys` methods accepts an iterable and creates a new dictionary with values set to that iterable.

In this case `q` is a number, suppose it is `123`. `str(q)` is the string `"123"`.
So `d.fromkeys(str(q))` is the dictionary `{'1': None, '2': None, '3': None }`.

You the set `w` to the list of the keys. So `w` is `['1', '2', '3']`.

In the end `d[int(w[0])]` tries to delete the key `1`. **But the code provides no guarantee that this key exist!**

When you entered the values in your previous loop you may not have inserted any `1` key!

From the code I *guess* that you want to obtain the maximum value and remove it.

If you wanted to remove the maximum element you should have done:

```
key, val = max(d.items(), key=lambda x_y: x_y[1])
del d[key]
```

here `max` finds the `(key, value)` pair inside the dictionary with the maximum value and then deletes it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the mistake i made. :)